# Clone object in another language and modify fields

Tags: plone

Using LinguaPlone we can translate a single object in another language. Usually we obtain a new instance of the same object-type with all the fields blank. We have to fill the (blank) fields and then save all. The catalog for the translations is committed and upgraded.

I wrote two new AT content-type. Almost of all fields of the object must be untranslated in the various language (we've also two image fields and file field).

So, is there a method (or addon) to clone an object as it is changing on the fly only the language-field and the translation catalog?

(Plone 4.2, last version of linguaplone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the `languageIndependent=True` flag is for in your schema. Use it to flag any field that does *not* need to be translated and it'll be copied over for you.

By setting the flag, you mark a field as only editable in the canonical copy, all translations are automatically updated whenever you modify such a field.